# Printing items inside a list which have an element that occurs n times without using itemgetter

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, matrix

Having a 2D list, how do you find the elements inside the inner lists that occurs n time? For example, if:

```
>>> lst=[['Hey','Job','1998'],['No','Andrew','2011'],['Yes','Jack','2020'],['Pas','Job','2176'],['Hand','Andrew','1934'],['Fry','Job','1981']]
```

And the n occurence I'm looking for is at least 2, i.e. n >= 2.

**How can I print something like below?**

```
>>> Job with 3 occurrences
>>> Andrew with 2 occurrences
```

My attempt was not successful. And it also wasn't able to print as I wished above. Here it is:

```
>>> num = 2
>>> answer = [y for y in lst if lst.count(y[1]) >= int(num)]
>>> for i in answer:
        a = ", ".join(str(x) for x in i) 
        print(a)
```

If possible, avoid all kinds of collections such as dictionaries, maps or itemgetter. I would love seeing how a clever programmer would work this out using only lists and tuples.

Comment: why so many restrictions?

Comment: It's just that I like learning how to get to an answer with as much obstacles as possible. Sorry for giving you a hard time.

Comment: So many restrictions. At least can we use groupby from itertools module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another way, similar to the one of Jin, but with only one extra list and count on the fly

```
>>> lst=[['Hey','Job','1998'],['No','Andrew','2011'],['Yes','Jack','2020'],['Pas','Job','2176'],['Hand','Andrew','1934'],['Fry','Job','1981']]    
>>> count=[]
>>> for _,name,_ in lst:  
        ready=False
        for i,(_,n) in enumerate(count):
            if name==n:
                count[i][0] += 1
                ready=True
                break
        if not ready:
            count.append( [1,name] )


>>> count.sort(reverse=True)
>>> count
[[3, 'Job'], [2, 'Andrew'], [1, 'Jack']]
>>> for c,n in count:
        if c>=2:
            print("{} with {} occurrences".format(n,c))


Job with 3 occurrences
Andrew with 2 occurrences
>>>
```

Comment: Did you take the previous comment in consideration? I mean, did you make sure that the name with the most superfluous is always first or is it just almost exactly like Jim? I would really appreciate it if you did that. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, It shouldn't be 'Job' with 3 superfluous but just Job. I know. It's my fault I previously asked.

Comment: yes, I considered that, that is why I put the count first followed by the name, to make more easy the posterior sorting with `count.sort(reverse=True)`, the reverse is to indicate that I want descended order

Answer (score 2):

With the restriction that no external modules are allowed, this is how I'd write it:

```
result = {}

for _, name, _ in lst:
  if name in result:
    result[name] += 1
  else:
    result[name] = 1

num = 2
for name, count in result.items():
  if count >= num:
    print("'{}' with {} occurrences".format(name, count))
```

If you were allowed to use additional modules, a much simpler solution would be to use a `Counter` object:

```
from collections import Counter
result = Counter(name for _, name, _ in lst)
```

Comment: However, is there a way with neither dictionaries nor imported modules? Sorry for giving you a hard time. You and Adam are both using `dict`. Is there another clever way?

Comment: No, you really need a dictionary for this, the only alternative I can think of would be implementing your own dictionary, which would be silly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way using only lists and tuples and no other collections (such as a dictionaries or maps).

Comment: Sure - but in the end you'd be implementing a dictionary by hand. It's not fun to work on a problem with such artificial restrictions.

Comment: I know it's no fun. But, could you give me that favor by showing me how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only other approach you could use involves two extra lists and, in all honesty, is a sub-par solution in comparison to the `dict` one that Oscar suggested.

You could do it, though, by creating a list of all relevant elements:

```
l = [i[1] for i in lst]
```

and then looping through these, `count`ing their occurrence and adding them to a `seen` list so you don't `count` and `print` again:

```
seen = []
for i in l:
    if i in seen:
        continue
    c = l.count(i)
    if c >= 2:
        print("{} with {} occurences".format(i, c))
        seen.append(i)
```

This prints out your wanted output.

```
Job with 3 occurences
Andrew with 2 occurences
```

You could use a `set` as `seen` for better performance of the `if i in seen` by using `seen = {}` and changing `seen.append` to `seen.add`. That's your call though, maybe sets are off the table too :-).

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard There's something wrong with the code. It only prints Job with 3 occurences. Not Andrew with 2 occurrences as well.

Comment: Are you certain @TedIdzikowski? Executing it again using your sample input yields both `Job with 3 occurences` and `Andrew with 2 occurences` for me.

Comment: Silly me. I found out that I didn't include the `if c >= 2: ...` in the loop. It was outside the loop.

Comment: I have a question. Is there a way, though, to always make sure that it prints in an exact order starting with the 'Name' with greatest number of occurrence first just like you did, but for every case as it didn't work for other cases. Thanks.

Comment: @TedIdzikowski yes, save in a list the element and its count, sorted it by count and them print

Comment: @TedIdzikowski You could change the loop to instead create a list of `(Name, count)` tuples and then sort that list based on the `count` if you need ordering. Then you can proceed to print that list out as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `get` method on python `dicts` which is the same thing as `dict[key]` except if the key is not in the dictionary it returns the second argument:

```
counts = {}

for _, name, _ in lst:
    counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

for name, count in counts:
    if count < n:
        continue
    print("'{}' with {} occurrences".format(name, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You updated your question a lot of times and i was trying to give you a new approch to have the same output as you gave.

As i see your last update you said that you want to

> avoid all kinds of collections such as dictionaries, maps or
>   itemgetter. And you would love seeing how a clever programmer would work
>   this out using only lists and tuple

So, in my solution i will use `groupby` from `itertools` module. And my approch is like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst=[['Hey','Job','1998'],['No','Andrew','2011'],['Yes','Jack','2020'],['Pas','Job','2176'],['Hand','Andrew','1934'],['Fry','Job','1981']]
groups = {}

for k, _ in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[1]):
    if k not in groups:
        groups[k] = 1
    else:
        groups[k] +=1

print("\n".join(x for x in ["'{0}' with {1} occurences".format(i, groups[i]) for i in groups if groups[i] >=2]))
```

Output:

```
'Job' with 3 occurences
'Andrew' with 2 occurences
```

Comment: Well, he updated a lot of time his question when i was trying to figure out a new approch for my answer. I think no one here used groupby in his solution this is why i posted my answer.